# jQuery Resizable Plugin Cursor Corruption

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

If you are using a custom cursor on your page, `resizable()` plug-in reverts it to default pointer after getting interaction. I checked the plugin documentation at ***https://jqueryui.com/resizable/*** but there is no explanation of disabling plugin's resize cursors to keep page's custom cursor always. Is there a hacky way to achieve this?

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable(
{
    //hack
});
```

Comment: Disable all cursors .. meaning ?

Comment: You want to keep the pointer style which was there before you apply resizeable ?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas Definitely like that. But also I don't want to show built-in resize cursors. I just want that custom cursor is showing always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#resizable").css('cursor','pointer');
    //more css styles here
    },
    containment: "#container"
});
```

Comment: `containment` ? for the cursor you need to add the style you want to in the function

Comment: for `containment` you can set height and width of the container as given in its documentation

Comment: You can mark my answer as the answer so that this topic gets closed

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is not working in the expected way.

Comment: I have updated the code ... can you try and let me know